# ASP.NET Core MVC if statement in view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET Core MVC if statement in view

Is there a way to have an if statement change the text displayed in a field?
I want to display **"None"** if the date field is `09/09/9999`.
Since date fields can't be null, I use that date to indicate no due date.

I tried this but get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `System.DateTime`.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@if (@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item.DueDate)) == "09/09/9999")
{
    item.DueDate = "None";
} else 
{
    @Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item.DueDate))
}
```

Comment: How the `DueDate` is declared? Is it `DateTime DueDate  { get; set; }`?

Comment: Date fields **can** be null if you declare them as nullable: `public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }`

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to include that.
    
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(9999, 09, 09);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it as nullable:

```
 public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

and check in the view:

```cs
@if (item.DueDate.HasValue)
{
  @Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item.DueDate))  
}
else
{
    @:None
}
```

With this syntax if the `item.DueDate` is not defined the **`None`** will be displayed.